# Filtering in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm grouping rotten tomatoes scores by director with the following:

```
director_counts = bigbadpanda.groupby(["Director"]).size().order(ascending = False)

print director_counts ---> 

Director
Woody Allen             44
Alfred Hitchcock        38
Clint Eastwood          32
Martin Scorsese         29
Steven Spielberg        29
Sidney Lumet            25
...
```

**Question:**
What's the best way for me to filter by directors with more than 2 movies?

For filtering by the average movies per director would this work? `bigbadpanda.groupby(["Director"]).size().mean()`)

Comment: Can you post the source data here? There might be a more optimal approach to what you're doing.

Comment: I just checked out the documentation under 'filtration'. Try this: `director_counts.groupby(director_counts["Director"]).filter(lambda: x: x>2 )` for filtering by > 2 movies. I will add to this in a sec

Answer (score 1):

Data I created based on your info

```
Director,Movies
Woody Allen,44
Alfred Hitchcock,38
Clint Eastwood,32
Someone,2
Someone else,1
```

Simply do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt')

print(df[df.Movies > 2])
```

Output:

```
           Director  Movies
0       Woody Allen      44
1  Alfred Hitchcock      38
2    Clint Eastwood      32
```